# Match [A](B) but not ![A](B)

Tags: regex

I cant get this to work.
I'm trying to match A and B from `[A](B)`, but it should only do the matching if it doesn't start with `!`.

I've this so far.
`/\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/`

It matches A and B, but If I add `[^\!]` it wont match anything.

`/[^\!]\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/`

The value `![A](B)` can be anywhere in a larger string.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: what do you mean by "it wont match anything"? [A](B) isn't matched anymore by your new pattern /[^\!]\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/ ?

Comment: /[^\!]\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/ won't match `[A](B)`.

Comment: What regex flavor/programming language?

Comment: what about trying to match beginning of string: ([^\!]|^)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in TextPad (it's all I have for regex at the moment. you'll probably have to modify the escaping):

```
\(^\|[^\!]\)\[[^]]+\]([^)]+)
```

The `\(^\|[^\!]\)` matches either the beginning of the line or a character other than `!`.

Answer (score 2):

if the regex your are using supports lookbehind's then the following should work

```
(?<!!)\[A\]\(B\)
```

The first group means that there is not a ! behind

Comment: Lookbehind isn't supported, I'm using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `([^!]|^)(\[A\]\(B\))`

Comment: I'm having some problem with it (`/([^!]|^)\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/gm`). It matches `[A](B)`, `[A](B) [C](D)` but not `[A](B)[C](D)`. Any ideas why?

Comment: matches all your samples with me

Comment: --
[22:15:15.022] /([^!]|^)\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/gm.test('[A](B)[C](D)')

[22:15:15.029] true

Comment: It returns this in Ruby `[["[", "](B", "](B"], [")", "C](D", "C](D"]]` and raises an error in JavaScript. `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([^!]|^)[([^]]+)](([^)]+))/: Unmatched ')'`

Comment: yes, because this `/([^!]|^)\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/` is not the same as what you are trying `/([^!]|^)[([^]]+)](([^)]+))/`. My solution is still valid, the problem is your code ;-)

Comment: `/([^!]|^)\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/gm` returns `["[A](B)"]` in JavaScript and `[["", "A", "B"]]` in Ruby. I'm I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use look-behind assertions, you can use two different regexes with a logical connective:

```
/\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/ && !(/!\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/)
```